# Give an example of convergent sum

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

[image]
[image]

I do it like that 
[image]
but my teacher told me that  an^2 diverge since n^1/2 by p-series diverge.Can someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but could perhaps be stated more clearly. Set
$$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log n}$$
then
$$a_n^2=\frac{1}{n\log(n)^2}$$
and $\sum a_n^2$ converges by the given theorem (since $2>1$). On the other hand
$$\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{n\log n} $$
and $\sum a_n/\sqrt{n}$ diverges by the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your teacher misunderstood your example.  You could have presented it better, by stating right at the beginning:
$$a_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n} \log n}$$

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but your exposition was unclear. If $a_n = 1/(\sqrt{n}\log n)$ then $a_n^2 = 1/(n (\log n)^2)$ so this series converges by theorem 3.29. But $a_n/\sqrt{n} = 1/(n \log n)$ so again by the theorem this series diverges.